# how to resolve " HTTPConnectionPool: Max retries exceeded with url" exception when trying to download from a magnet link on python 3.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im new here so please forgive me if im posting off topic or something. I just got into python and i just wanted to try out something so i wrote this program to try and download a torrent from a magnet link on THEPIRATEBAY but i kept getting this "Max retries reached with url" exception apparently Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'. Im using Python 3.5.1 on Windows 10. I searched for solutions online but almost all of them just suggested that i add sleep(1) between requests so i dont send too many requests, which i tried and it didnt work. any input would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import socket
import os
import subprocess
import tabulate
import sys
import requests 
i = 0

def select_torrent():
    torrent = input("SELECT A TORRENT")
    return torrent

def download_torrent(url):
    try:
        fname = "myfirsttorrent.torrent"
        response = requests.get(url,stream=True)
        f=open(fname,'wb')
        for buffer in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            if buffer:
                f.write(buffer)
                f.flush()
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print("EXCEPTION",str(e))
        sys.exit(1)

    return fname


def crawler():
    search_url_prefix = "https://thepiratebay.se/search/"
    search_input = input("ENTER WHAT YOU WANNA SEARCH FOR")
    search_url = search_url_prefix + search_input + "/0/99/0"
    data = requests.get(search_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content)
    title = [t.get_text() for t in soup.findAll('a',{'class':'detLink'})]
    magnet_link = ["http://"+m.get('href') for m in soup.findAll('a',{'title':'Download this torrent using magnet'})]
    details = [d.get_text() for d in soup.findAll('font',{'class':'detDesc'})]
    seeds_leech = [s.get_text() for s in soup.findAll('td',{'align':'right'})]
    seeds = seeds_leech[0::2]
    leech = seeds_leech[1::2]
    table = [[str(i+1),title[i],details[i],seeds[i],leech[i]]for i in range(len(magnet_link))]
    print()
    print(tabulate.tabulate(table,headers=['No','TITLE','DETAILS','SEEDS','Leech']))
    torrent = select_torrent()
    print('DOWNLOADING .... '+title[int(torrent)-1])
    print(magnet_link[int(torrent)-1])
    fname=download_torrent(magnet_link[int(torrent)-1])
    #subprocess.Popen(['xgd-open',fname],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    #os.startfile(magnet_link[int(torrent)-1])

crawler()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with requests, you need a torrent client to download using the magnet link. I used  [Transmissions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TransmissionHowTo) *transmission-cli* on Ubuntu to download, you just need to find a suitable client for windows:

```
def crawler():
    search_url_prefix = "https://thepiratebay.se/search/"
    search_input = raw_input("ENTER WHAT YOU WANNA SEARCH FOR")
    search_url = search_url_prefix + search_input + "/0/99/0"
    data = requests.get(search_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content)
    title = [t.get_text() for t in soup.findAll('a',{'class':'detLink'})]
    magnet_link = [m.get('href') for m in soup.findAll('a',{'title':'Download this torrent using magnet'})]
    torrent = select_torrent()
    print('DOWNLOADING .... '+title[int(torrent)-1])

    subprocess.Popen(["transmission-cli",magnet_link[int(torrent)-1]])
```

Also don't add http to the magnet link, use it as above. There is an unofficial cygwin windows build of the  [Transmission BitTorrent daemon](https://sourceforge.net/projects/transmissiondaemon/). If you want to block until complete use `subprocess.check_call`

Comment: .Thank You for your answer..I just used Utorrent. Is there a library like libtorrent for python 3.5? i've been searching for one for a few days now.